# JavaScript custom .sort() of double array object using .localeCompare() not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, compare

I was working on a solution to a leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/sender-with-largest-word-count/) when I hit a scenario I spent hours trying to debug and still can't figure out what's going on. To simplify, given an object:

```
let items = [
  [ 'K', 4 ],           [ 'kFIbpoFxn', 10 ],  [ 'yErgn', 6 ],
  [ 'N', 8 ],           [ 'wtJesr', 9 ],      [ 'rusffeL', 14 ],
  [ 'KlpoodEd', 5 ],    [ 'qGcQqIVdFr', 1 ],  [ 'ztmCdK', 10 ],
  [ 'HFILjKln', 12 ],   [ 'TmmQZ', 18 ],      [ 'R', 7 ],
  [ 'CNh', 7 ],         [ 'YMQDBkOWy', 22 ],  [ 'kjiSc', 4 ],
  [ 'cGMsZxxx', 6 ],    [ 'PPqsmNBewN', 21 ], [ 'gbtn', 10 ],
  [ 'nQNcL', 8 ],       [ 'rK', 10 ],         [ 'ppr', 16 ],
  [ 'LhSVp', 11 ],      [ 'Ub', 7 ],          [ 'QGRFMLY', 11 ],
  [ 'SdDObYkD', 9 ],    [ 'q', 3 ],           [ 'suAakSCuHz', 6 ],
  [ 'dnzhjdwrEt', 8 ],  [ 'ubIEXAO', 22 ],    [ 'EsBuLal', 11 ],
  [ 'xlQqQRrdTv', 12 ], [ 'mWxCG', 8 ],       [ 'DmwIEmS', 5 ],
  [ 'nBQLLS', 6 ],      [ 'QhF', 4 ],         [ 'bmtYQKYv', 5 ],
  [ 'PRiNk', 7 ],       [ 'QyYJw', 7 ],       [ 'QIFauTN', 3 ],
  [ 'zJLcUq', 13 ],     [ 'TU', 1 ],          [ 'lCkGjDY', 7 ],
  [ 'A', 6 ]
]
```

I am attempting to sort it based first on highest integer, but if those values are equal, by largest lexicographical value, ie the .reverse() of how JS sorts strings by default

my sorting code is:

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[1] !== a[1] ? b[1] - a[1] : -a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
});
```

resulting in:

```
[
  [ 'YMQDBkOWy', 22 ], [ 'ubIEXAO', 22 ],    [ 'PPqsmNBewN', 21 ],
  [ 'TmmQZ', 18 ],     [ 'ppr', 16 ],        [ 'rusffeL', 14 ],
  [ 'zJLcUq', 13 ],    [ 'xlQqQRrdTv', 12 ], [ 'HFILjKln', 12 ],
  [ 'QGRFMLY', 11 ],   [ 'LhSVp', 11 ],      [ 'EsBuLal', 11 ],
  [ 'ztmCdK', 10 ],    [ 'rK', 10 ],         [ 'kFIbpoFxn', 10 ],
  [ 'gbtn', 10 ],      [ 'wtJesr', 9 ],      [ 'SdDObYkD', 9 ],
  [ 'nQNcL', 8 ],      [ 'N', 8 ],           [ 'mWxCG', 8 ],
  [ 'dnzhjdwrEt', 8 ], [ 'Ub', 7 ],          [ 'R', 7 ],
  [ 'QyYJw', 7 ],      [ 'PRiNk', 7 ],       [ 'lCkGjDY', 7 ],
  [ 'CNh', 7 ],        [ 'yErgn', 6 ],       [ 'suAakSCuHz', 6 ],
  [ 'nBQLLS', 6 ],     [ 'cGMsZxxx', 6 ],    [ 'A', 6 ],
  [ 'KlpoodEd', 5 ],   [ 'DmwIEmS', 5 ],     [ 'bmtYQKYv', 5 ],
  [ 'QhF', 4 ],        [ 'kjiSc', 4 ],       [ 'K', 4 ],
  [ 'QIFauTN', 3 ],    [ 'q', 3 ],           [ 'TU', 1 ],
  [ 'qGcQqIVdFr', 1 ]
]
```

the issue is 'ubIEXAO' should be sorted ahead of 'YMQDBkOWy'. when you do the isolated -a.compareLocale(b) it works correctly***, and in other test cases this part of the code correctly sorts other strings. but not in this test case. what am I missing? thank you!

(I know there are myriad other ways to solve this problem, I just want to know why this sort function isn't working as intended for this object)

***UPDATE from reading some of the comments I just realized that I was only half testing this. Initially I checked for what value the -localeCompare returned and then hardcoded that value into a sort to verify the output. As it turns out, for some reason, hardcoding a -1 returns a different result than the -localeCompare function itself, which also console logs a value of -1. I do not understand this interaction!

```js
let a = 'YMQDBkOWy';
let b = 'ubIEXAO';
console.log('localeCompare test: ' + -a.localeCompare(b))
let c = [a,b]
console.log(c.sort( (a,b) => {console.log('1'); return -a.localeCompare(b)}))
c = [a,b]
console.log(c.sort( (a,b) => {return -1}))
```

Comment: wait wait wait; why do you think that "ubIEXAO" should sort ahead of "YMQDBkOWy"?  The `.localeCompare()` function (for English at least) reverses the sense of upper-vs-lower case comparisons compared to plain string comparisons. So "A" sorts *after* "a" with `.localeCompare()`, but before with a plain `>` or `<` comparison because the Unicode numeric value of "A" is less than that of "a".

Comment: @mandy8055 I don't get it. Why would the result of `localeCompare` be unreliable? It's directly applicable to sorting. The note on the page just says to not rely on *specific* values, as in it may return `-1` or `-2` so, don't check for that. Instead you need to check for positive, negative, or zero. Which is the only thing `.sort()` takes into account already.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the comparison operators to make it case sensitive.

```js
items.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1] || (b[0] > a[0]) - (b[0] < a[0]));
```

Comment: @Pointy Are you referring to the comparator or the `.sort` method itself? `sort` is guaranteed to be a stable sort.

Comment: @Pointy Ref: [Tim sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#:~:text=Timsort%20is%20a%20stable%20sorting,merges%20runs%20of%20similar%20sizes) is stable if you're talking about algorithm stability.

Comment: @Pointy The comparator doesn't return 0 for any of those elements with the same count though since they have different names.

Comment: @Pointy The issue is `'Y'.localeCompare('u')` returns `> 0` while `'Y' < 'u'` is true. It appears to be doing a case insensitive comparison, even if the sensitivity option is set.

Comment: @Unmitigated deleting my comments, I must be more tired than I think. I believe the issue is with what `.localeCompare()` does in the "en" domain; it does caps vs lower "backwards" from plain "<" compare. (As you clearly said already!!)

Comment: @Pointy - it's weirder than that ... `AAA > aaa` but `AAA < aab`

Comment: @JaromandaX yea it's doing something that makes sense to somebody probably but I can't figure out what that is, nor can I find any clear documentation. I have definitely learned something I did not know.

Comment: @Unmitigated I tested your sort function and it works. can you go into a little more detail (for a noob like me) as to why the sort function I wrote doesn't work and yours does? Thank you!

Comment: @BinarySolo The `localeCompare` method behaves strangely for mixed case strings, but `>` and `<` work correctly.

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks! last request: can you look at my edited/updated post. I added executable code I used when trying to test this odd behavior, and that seems to surface another unexpected outcome that is in addition to case sensitivity (i think)

Comment: @BinarySolo If you're referring to `c.sort( (a,b) => {return -1})`, `() => -1` is not a valid comparator function since it's neither reflexive nor anti-symmetric.

Comment: @Unmitigated I don't know what those words mean in the context of JS/coding (b/c I'm a new) but I think maybe you're misinterpreting what I'm trying to do. I'm hardcoding the value the function is supposed to eval to, and yet it results in the opposite result

Comment: @BinarySolo The comparator can be called multiple times though, even if it's only sorting two elements. The comparator has to satisfy comp(a, a) == 0 and comp(a, b) == -comp(b, a). Just returning `-1` does not suffice. You can get inconsistent results by using an invalid comparator, so I do not think it's necessary to try to understand the behavior of that snippet.

Comment: @Unmitigated so I edited my post, updating the code snippet, adding another console.log that runs each time the sort is called for that isolated test case. It only logs once. Are you sure that comparator is being called multiple times when only 2 items are being sorted?

Comment: @BinarySolo I'm not saying that it necessarily is being called multiple times, but that it's essentially undefined behavior to use an invalid comparator.

Comment: @BinarySolo However, if you add `console.log(a,b)` inside the comparator, you'll see that the elements are being compared in the reverse order of what you expected, so you should have been returning `1` instead. In general, you should not attempt to rely on the order elements are compared in, how many times the comparator is called, or the like. And always use valid comparators.

Answer (score 0):

- *the issue is 'ubIEXAO' should be sorted ahead of 'YMQDBkOWy'. when you do the isolated -a.compareLocale(b) it works correctly*. In my case, the sort order is the same hence no discrepancy, per the code snippet below.

```js
const sample = [ 'YMQDBkOWy', 'LeMoN', 'yMQDBkOWy', 'ubIEXAO', 'UbIEXAO' ];

sample.sort( (a,b) => -a.localeCompare(b) );

console.log( sample );
```

The output is `[ "YMQDBkOWy", "yMQDBkOWy", "UbIEXAO", "ubIEXAO", "LeMoN" ]` which shows the two strings in the same order as the array of arrays: `"YMQDBkOWy", "ubIEXAO"`.

Comment: I updated my original post to include how I tested it and an inconsistency I just found, if you don't mind taking a look. I isolated the -localeCompare of these 2 strings which returns a value of -1 when 'YMQDBkOWy' is a and 'ubIEXAO' is b. But when I sort based on -localeCompare I get a different result than sorting with a hardcoded value of -1

Comment: I don't see what this answer is trying to say. The issue is exactly that `"YMQDBkOWy", "yMQDBkOWy"` is not the intended order.

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the order of `compareFn(a, b)` value.

`a` is the next item and `b` is the current item.

So in this case the return result is equal to 1, which is `> 0` so it will

**sort a after b, e.g. [b, a]**. [Sort order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description)

which is mean `b` will be placed before `a` ~ `[ 'YMQDBkOWy', 22 ]` before `[ 'ubIEXAO', 22 ]`

```js
a = [ 'ubIEXAO', 22 ]
b = [ 'YMQDBkOWy', 22 ]

-a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) =  1
```

```js
let items = [
  ["YMQDBkOWy", 22],
  ["ubIEXAO", 22],
];

items.sort(function (a, b) {
  console.log("a is second item", a);
  console.log("b is first item", b);

  console.log("-a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) = ", -a[0].localeCompare(b[0])); // 1

  return -a[0].localeCompare(b[0]); // 1  > 0
});
```

Comment: Your sort comparator is invalid.

Comment: Also the order of parameters passed to the comparator is not defined. The same two array elements *might* be passed to the comparator as "a" and "b" on one call, and as "b" and "a" on another. The sort comparator must return consistent results based on the comparison **values** of the two elements, regardless of the invocation.